# How to set different classes at runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, architecture

I am making a game in Unity C# where the character will have different characterstics and movement functions in each scene. So I am trying to have different scripts for a player in different scenes, while all of them inheriting from the same base class. The definition will be something like below

```
public class PlayerScript1 : PlayerBase { /* for scene 1*/
    public void Move(){
        /* my movement code*/
    }
}
```

Similarly, I have a separate class for Scene2 as

```
public class PlayerScript2 : PlayerBase { /* for scene 2*/
    public void Move(){
        /* my movement code*/
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, my other scripts, like HealthScript,ScoreScript etc they do not change with scene. But they do access PlayerScript1 script. And thats why, I have the PlayerScript1 declaration in them. Like below:

```
public class HealthScript : MonoBehaviour {
    PlayerScript1 playerScript;
    void Start(){
        /*accessing the script attached to game object*/
    }
}
```

So how can I have my Health Script access different instances of my PlayerScript based on the scene? I know I could use delegates to call different methods in runtime, but how can I do the same with classes?

Comment: Its hard to help if people can't understand your problem and the question. I think you should explain what you mean by "how do I manage different scenes to have different PlayerScripts"

Comment: Thanks Programmer. I have edited my question.

Comment: You want to access `PlayerScript1` script from your `HealthScript` script? If this is the case what's the name of GameObject the `PlayerScript1` script is attached to?

Comment: PlayerScript1 will be attached to the Player object in Scene1. Then in Scene2, PlayerScript2 (instead of PlayerScript1) will be attached to the same Player object. So I want to know a way to use PlayerScript1 or PlayerScript2  so that I can use the same HealthScript in all scenes while changing the PlayerScript attached to the Player object, since each script is written to perform different function for different scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered to my question on the Unity forum which cleared all my doubts:
The key was using the below line in my HealthScript :

```
PlayerBase player = (PlayerBase)FindObjectOfType(typeof(PlayerBase));
```

http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1348311/view.html

Comment: You can use the generic version for FindObjectOfType<PlayerBase>(). But this is only valid if you are sure to have only one instance of that type. Else it will pick the first one found and it may not be the one you want. Using singleton may solve too.

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I have my Health Script access different instances of my PlayerScript based on the scene?

Well first, you'll want to declare that object as of Type `PlayerBase` as you will be unable to assign an instance of PlayerScript2 to a variable of type PlayerScript1: those classes might inherit from the same parent, but they are *not the same* and you cannot convert from one to the other.

After that you will need to search for the player object in the scene, something like...

```
void Start(){
    playerScript = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerBase>();
}
```

Assuming, of course, that PlayerBase extends MonoBehaviour. If it doesn't you can't get a reference this way (as it won't exist in the scene at all).  Additionally if you want this health object to persist from scene to scene, you need to call [`DontDestroyOnLoad()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) for it (as well as remembering that if you don't start testing from Scene 1 where this object is, it won't exist at all, or if you have a copy in every scene, you'll have duplication problems).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Draco. But when I assign player script to the player object in hierarchy, do i assign PlayerBase or PlayerScript1 , depending on that i will do the GetComponent like you mentioned:      playerScript = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerBase>();

Comment: You won't be assigning anything in the inspector, because your manager will exist in multiple scenes, it will always need to refind the player every time. Because PlayerScript1 extends PlayerBase, GetComponent will find it, same for PlayerScript2, and so on.